# DIY solution for PHPDOC annotation block integration with Sphinx-doc (php.autodoc)

Tags: php, python-sphinx, phpdoc, autodoc

- JS has it: https://github.com/erikrose/sphinx-js
- Python has it: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html
- Java has it: http://bronto.github.io/javasphinx/
- Swift has it: https://github.com/AnarchyTools/anarchy_sphinx#swift-auto-documentation-extractor

PHP still does not have documentation extractor from source code.

Could you please suggest how to automatically extract PHPDOC annotations from my PHP code into my documentation written in sphinx (contextually) and if there is no such solution, how to make one (such as by using https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/tree/3.x) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### 2019 Update

The best tool to use this similar to php-parser is https://github.com/phpstan/phpdoc-parser

I use it along with php-parser to manipulate PHP in any possible way and it works great together.

Comment: I checked it out and here is no documentation or a guide. Can you suggest how it can be used? I still don't have any good solution to this.

Comment: This seems to be not too easy I'd say. It's really weird that nobody has developed and shared a library that generates rst from php code. This is unusual in the php community :D

Comment: I use it in Rector and EasyCodingStandard. It's not easy, but can be used :) I can write about it if you need. Just request a post: https://github.com/tomasvotruba/tomasvotruba.cz

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this same question today, and I found this tool which generates reStructuredText for each file for a namespace in a directory: https://github.com/varspool/sphpdox/

Directory structure, assuming you've you've installed `sphpdox` using composer and run `sphinx-quickstart` (detailed in http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html) in your documentation folder (I used `docs/` in this example:

```
src/
    YourNameSpace/
        YourClass.php
docs/
    Makefile
    source/
        index.rst
        conf.py
vendor/
    bin/
        sphpdox
```

To generate the reST for your namespace, you can now run:

```
./vendor/bin/sphpdox process "YourNameSpace" ./src -o ./docs/source
```

This will create a directory at `./docs/source/YourNameSpace`

To use the Sphinx PHP domain (which `sphpdox` uses), you must install [sphinxcontrib-phpdomain](https://github.com/markstory/sphinxcontrib-phpdomain):

```
pip3 install sphinxcontrib-phpdomain
```

Now add it to the list of extensions:

```
# ./docs/source/conf.py
extensions = [
    # ...
    "sphinxcontrib.phpdomain"
]
```

Now you can link to the generated directory in your sphinx index:

```
# ./docs/source/index.rst

.. toctree::
    YourNameSpace/index
```

And to generate the output with a builder, now run `make [builder]` (e.g. `make html`)

To generate the PHP reST files automatically when you run a builder, you can modify the `Makefile`:

```
# ./docs/Makefile

php:
    @../vendor/bin/sphpdox process "YourNameSpace" ../src/ -o ./source

%: php
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```

Comment: would that overwrite the .rst files if i change them manually?

Comment: @romaninsh yes, it generates all of those files when the sphpdox command is run

Comment: this is not useful in my case. The reason I'm using Sphinx is for flexible documentation format, there are better way to convert PHPDOC into HTML. Thanks for answer though.